# Administrative issues usin LDAP Authentication in .Net

Tags: .net, ldap

Most of code samples used to authenticate users in a LDAP server looks like this:

```
Public Function Authenticate(ByVal userName As String, ByVal password As String) As Data.User

   Dim root As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + _server, userName, password)
   Dim search As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(root)
   Dim user As User = Nothing

   search.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree
   search.Filter = "(sAMAccountName=" + userName + ")"

   Dim results As SearchResultCollection = search.FindAll()

   If (Not (results Is Nothing)) Then

       user = _GetUser(results(0).Path)

   End If

   Return user

End Function
```

I haven't set up the LDAP server of my client. The code above works only for administrators' accounts. What I noticed was that only Administrators can effectively query on LDAP servers. This may be a choice of the admin for security issues. This is reasonable for me, but I'm not sure if this is the truly reason for what is happening.

I googled for different solutions, but the majority of them seems like the previous code. In my case, I will try to use a special LDAP account to query on the server and, once logged in, look for the user that is trying to authenticate.

Is this the best approach?

Comment: have you tried querying the ldap server through ldp.exe? The result will let you know if your desired username is actually allowed to access the query information or if it something in your code. In my case I can query my test Active Directory through non-admin account just fine (where allowed by permissions)

Comment: Great tip. I've got some additional information using it. But I got something interesting. If I try to connect to the server using only the IP Address of the LDAP server, I can authenticate with the ordinary users, but I still cannot query the server. Appending to the server ip "dc=company,dc=com", only admin can connect and it's possible to query the server. I'm don't know well LDAP, but I think I will have to call two times the authentication - one to validate user/password and another to query the server. This does not sound good for me.

Comment: I finally decide to use the approach that I described originally. First of all, I try to bind the actual user to the LDAP server. After being that sucessfully, I bind to the server using an special user, with permissions to query the server. From that, I can query users, groups etc. Talking to a friend who works with LDAP, this is maybe the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should query twice, one for validate and other for querying. 
Here is the code in C#:

---

string directoryEntryFinalDetails = "LDAP:///DC=xyz,DC=com";

DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(directoryEntryDetails);

directoryEntry.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;

**directoryEntry.Username = General.DecryptedUserName;

directoryEntry.Password = General.DecryptedPassword;**

DirectorySearcher directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry);

DirectorySearcher directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry);

directorySearcher.Filter = "";

foreach (SearchResult resultSet in directorySearcher.FindAll())

{

```
//your code
```

}

---

just let me know whether this helps!!

Comment: Sorry, but It didn't work. FindAll throws and exception (something like "There is no such object in server"). Thank you anyway.